# windows authentication

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, jsp-tags

Using a JSP page I get username and password.  How do I check this in active directory. Please give example with some code.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific and you need to describe your question more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Java example](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2007/05/14/1429.aspx) ... hopefully this helps.